# Button setOnClickListener on for loop

Tags: android, buttonclick

I have 10 buttons and i want to set OnClickListener for all that buttons. Also  with clicking on any button app will go another activity. I only post the buttons' definitions on the activity class. My code;

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
Button button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
Button buttons[] = {button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10};
final String urlOfButtons[] = {"","","","","","","","","","",""};
final String titles[] = {"","","","","","","","","","",""};

JsonNode itemNode = jsonNode.path("Docs");
for(int i=0 ; i<itemNode.size() ; i++){
    titles[i] = itemNode.get(i).path("Text").asText();
            title = titles[i];
    buttons[i].setText(title);
    urlOfButtons[i] = itemNode.get(i).path("Link").asText();
            url = urlOfButtons[i];
    buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(HouseDetail.this, HouseDetailPdf.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            intent.putExtra("url", url);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

This only takes the last values of title and url normally. String url, title is defined on top of class. Every button i click the same value goes to other activity. I want 10 different values to add extra. So i want to add instead of title and url; titles[i] and url[i] as extra. I hope i'm clear.

Comment: Are you adding these buttons programmatically or in your xml layout?

Comment: i m adding these buttons on layout of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `title` and `url` as tag to each button

```
buttons[i].setTag(1, title);
buttons[i].setTag(2, url);
```

and rerieve the tag inside `onClick`

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(HouseDetail.this, HouseDetailPdf.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", v.getTag(1));
            intent.putExtra("url", v.getTag(2));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Or else you can do something like this.Store the `index` as the tag so that you can get the `index` when the `button` is clicked.

```
buttons[i].setTag(i);
```

Get the `index` which is stored as `tag`.

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(HouseDetail.this, HouseDetailPdf.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", titles[position]);
            intent.putExtra("url", urlOfButtons[position]);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: I used the top one. Very useful idea i will never forget that way :)

Comment: I belive second solution is better than the first as it saves little memory:)

Comment: I will try that also :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

You have passed the `title` and `url` values to the next Activity. But, at the end of `for loop` the `title` and `url` will only have the last value of the for loop. So, irrespective of the `button click` only the last stored values in `title` and `url` will only go to the next activity.

You can make use of the `setTag(int key, Object tag)` and set the `url` and `title` values for the `button` as tags inside `for loop` and you can retrieve them inside `button` click using `getTag(int key)` method..

```
JsonNode itemNode = jsonNode.path("Docs");
for(int i=0 ; i<itemNode.size() ; i++){
    titles[i] = itemNode.get(i).path("Text").asText();
            title = titles[i];
    buttons[i].setText(title);

    urlOfButtons[i] = itemNode.get(i).path("Link").asText();
            url = urlOfButtons[i];

    buttons[i].setTag(1,title);
    buttons[i].setTag(2,url);

    buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(HouseDetail.this, HouseDetailPdf.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", v.getTag(1));
            intent.putExtra("url", v.getTag(2));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

[setTag(int key, Object tag);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29)

[getTag(int key);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28int%29)

Comment: I tried that but i values can not be token on onclicklistener.

Comment: Change modifier of 'i' to final . Eclipse gives that suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is right. By the time `onClick` gets called, the `for` loop has run to completion and `i` will always equal `itemNode.size()` (that's if you can get the compiler to let it through, which I doubt - java has a syntax rule that frowns on this sort of thing)

Comment: Yo, Tamilan: at the moment your suggestion creates 10 `OnClickListener`s with identical code and it's making the garbage collector sad... (not very sad, but you know. Sadness is best avoided :) )

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but i have used another answer. Your solution is also works.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the relevant `title` and `url` in each iteration of the loop and store them in something final, then you can use them in the `onClickListener`.

```
for(int i=0 ; i<itemNode.size() ; i++){
    final String title = itemNode.get(i).path("Text").asText();
    final String url = itemNode.get(i).path("Link").asText();
    buttons[i].setOnClickListener(/* same as you had before */);
}
```

(warning: untested code).

Obviously if you're using the titles and urls arrays somewhere else, you should assign the values there too.

Comment: Also i should change modifier of 'int i' to final? Then what about i++ on for loop?

Comment: Nope. You only need `i` to be final if you refer to it from inside the body of the `OnClickListener`. In the code I suggested, for every iteration of the loop, we create a new variable `title` and a new variable `url` that are based on `i`. Then each time around we construct a new `OnClickListener` that depends on the `title` and the `url`. So `i` can change and track through the loop, and `title` and `url` are unchanging from the point of view of each `OnClickListener`

Comment: @abhishek V's answer is better than this, though - why have 10 `OnClickListener`s when one will do?

Answer (score 0):

Your class should implement onclickListner like this:

```
public class HomeScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

Initialize your buttons:

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
button3.setOnClickListener(this);
Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
butto4.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Handle the click item for all buttons:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {        
        case R.id.button1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(HouseDetail.this, HouseDetailPdf.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            intent.putExtra("url", url);
startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
                Intent intent = new Intent(HouseDetail.this, HouseDetailPdf.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            intent.putExtra("url", url);
startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
                Intent intent = new Intent(HouseDetail.this, HouseDetailPdf.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            intent.putExtra("url", url);
startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
                Intent intent = new Intent(HouseDetail.this, HouseDetailPdf.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            intent.putExtra("url", url);
startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to make it is avoiding this loop. Just define the url and the title in xml file.

you could put this in your button definition:

```
android:tag="title|url"
```

and then, in the onClickListener you should put:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getTag() != null){
                        String[] details = v.getTag().split("|");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(HouseDetail.this, HouseDetailPdf.class);
                        intent.putExtra("title", details[0]);
                        intent.putExtra("url", details[1]);
                        startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

And then, the loop just could be used to setOnClickButtonListener(listener);
But sure, you must define this listener as the code above.